# Trigger event on third lambda failure

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to figure out how I can determine if a lambda function is being run for the third time. When I schedule a lambda function to run in cloudwatch the lambda function will run as expected. Sometimes the function fails on the first try. Lambda by default will run the function three times. Usually, on the second attempt, the function has no problem and runs as expected.

The problem is we have another Lambda function that fires when there is a failure. This function will send a slack message on failure. Because these functions recover on the second attempt so ofter I really want to find a way to know if this is the third attempt or not. I know I can do something like adding a record to Redis then check Redis whenever you run to see which attempt number this is but I'd rather not go that route.

Thanks

```
'''
Follow these steps to configure the webhook in Slack:

  1. Navigate to https://<your-team-domain>.slack.com/services/new

  2. Search for and select "Incoming WebHooks".

  3. Choose the default channel where messages will be sent and click "Add Incoming WebHooks Integration".

  4. Copy the webhook URL from the setup instructions and use it in the next section.

To encrypt your secrets use the following steps:

  1. Create or use an existing KMS Key - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/create-keys.html

  2. Expand "Encryption configuration" and click the "Enable helpers for encryption in transit" checkbox

  3. Paste <SLACK_CHANNEL> into the slackChannel environment variable

  Note: The Slack channel does not contain private info, so do NOT click encrypt

  4. Paste <SLACK_HOOK_URL> into the kmsEncryptedHookUrl environment variable and click "Encrypt"

  Note: You must exclude the protocol from the URL (e.g. "hooks.slack.com/services/abc123").

  5. Give your function's role permission for the `kms:Decrypt` action using the provided policy template
'''

import boto3
import json
import logging
import os

from base64 import b64decode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError


# The base-64 encoded, encrypted key (CiphertextBlob) stored in the kmsEncryptedHookUrl environment variable
ENCRYPTED_HOOK_URL = os.environ['kmsEncryptedHookUrl']
# The Slack channel to send a message to stored in the slackChannel environment variable
SLACK_CHANNEL = os.environ['slackChannel']

HOOK_URL = "https://" + boto3.client('kms').decrypt(
    CiphertextBlob=b64decode(ENCRYPTED_HOOK_URL),
    EncryptionContext={'LambdaFunctionName': os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME']}
)['Plaintext'].decode('utf-8')

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Event: " + str(event))
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    logger.info("Message: " + str(message))

    alarm_name = message['AlarmName']
    #old_state = message['OldStateValue']
    new_state = message['NewStateValue']
    reason = message['NewStateReason']

    slack_message = {
        'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
        'text': "%s state is now %s: %s" % (alarm_name, new_state, reason)
    }

    req = Request(HOOK_URL, json.dumps(slack_message).encode('utf-8'))
    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        response.read()
        logger.info("Message posted to %s", slack_message['channel'])
    except HTTPError as e:
        logger.error("Request failed: %d %s", e.code, e.reason)
    except URLError as e:
        logger.error("Server connection failed: %s", e.reason)
```

Comment: I see several possible options - use a database (like Redis or dynamodb) to save the state of executions calls.; use step functions with your lambda to control the execution of the flow and in case of several failures do fallback operation

Comment: Doing a fallback is easy. The issue is determining which failure im on.

Comment: If you use stepfunction you can modify input of lambda (increment counter) and then pass it to the sf

Comment: Awesome i will try that.

Comment: Also you can try to implement such handling using sqs&dlq. If message fails specified number of times then it goes to the dlq and fallback scenario is applied to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this old question to give an answer after gaining a bunch of experience. You just have to set the number of retries the lambda should do. The lambda isn’t considered “failed” until it fails after you’ve used up your retries. That was the part I didn’t understand. So after it truly fails you can send a message to sqs or a number of services. You just have to set the destination on failure to whatever you want.

Hope this helps someone else who didnt understand this.